Apache TinkerPop Gremlin query language is not getting converted to Neptune-specific steps that are optimized to run on the underlying Neptune engine
I am using  explain() API on AWS neptune cluster as below-
GraphTraversalSource g = getTraversal(cluster);
TraversalExplanation explain = g.V().hasLabel("Users").explain();
System.out.println(explain.prettyPrint());

Below 3 traversal ie., original , remote and final traversal are being printed.
Traversal Explanation-
Original Traversal   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(Users)])]
RemoteStrategy [D]   [RemoteStep(DriverServerConnection-neptune-cluster:8182 [graph=g])
]
Final Traversal      [RemoteStep(DriverServerConnection-neptune-cluster:8182 [graph=g])
]

But as per mentioned in doc, the below options are also getting printed while using the explain API. What changes are required in above code in order to print the below additional steps using java code.
Original Traversal,
Converted Traversal,
Neptune steps:,
Optimized Traversal,
Neptune steps:,
Predicates,
AWS Document refernence link- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-explain-api.html

The explain() step returns the TinkerPop explain output.  To get the Neptune Gremlin Explain (or Profile) outputs, you need to send the query to the appropriate API endpoint for such.
If you want to do this in Java, the easiest was is using the AWS Java SDK and the NeptunedataClient: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/neptunedata/NeptunedataClient.html
There are APIs for both executeGremlinExplainQuery and  executeGremlinProfileQuery.
If you're using a Neptune Notebook instance, you can also see the output of a Neptune Explain/Profile output for Gremlin queries using either:
%%grmelin explain
or
%%gremlin profile
when running Gremlin from a notebook cell.
